# Problems using Metakit for Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, dll

I'm having problems trying to use Metakit for Python on Windows. It always report this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#86>", line 1, in <module>
    import metakit
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\metakit.py", line 22, in <module>
    from Mk4py import *
ImportError: No module named Mk4py
```

I've already:

- Downloaded metakit.py and Mk4py.dll from http://equi4.com/pub/mk/ (official release)
- Copied metatkit.py to C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\
- Copied Mk4py.dll to C:\Python27\DLLs\

I have installed Python 2.7.5 win32 version

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and couldn't get the system to work with the provided dlls. I also tried compiling metakit from source to make it work and installing it from an the official source via egg, which failed in the same way (as it compiles from source).

Using my older windows XP machine with visual studio 2002 I managed to build it from source and install it with just a minor change of the setup script (changing every instance of msvc60 to msvc70 in the setup script). However, copying those files to my windows 8 machine still failed, and even copying what appeared to be the changes were unsuccessful.

In the end I copied my entire python directory from the xp machine to the windows 8 machine and now it is working without issues.

Obviously i could provide my dlls but I doubt they would be any more successful than the provided ones.

My next step is to reduce my reliance on having to use metakit as it seems very poorly supported.